# DNN 7 Redirects every request to getting started page

Tags: c#-4.0, dotnetnuke

I have a new installation of DNN7, everything installed fine, but when I go to the home page, it redirects to Getting Started, and the popup flashes up then disappears.

I click on another page, it starts loading, then immediately redirects again to Getting started.

i downloaded the source 07.01.02

it seems to me the page loads then after it is loaded it redirects to the getting started page

very odd, anyone any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so this is not a good solution, but i didnt want to really dig into this

on default.aspx.cs line 963 i just had ShowGettingStartedPage return false

i wouldnot really recommend it , in my case its ok since i be making other changes to dnn

thanks 
amir

Comment: it may work now, but as soon as you do a dnn upgrade, your site would break again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the database, try going into the Tabs table, and marking the Getting Started page as deleted, or if you can access the control panel try it from there.

I'm sure there is a flag somewhere in DNN that isn't being set, typically that page only flashes up the FIRST time the page is loaded.

Comment: great thank you, i think i am one step closer, but now i am stuck in an infinite loop where the home page keeps refreshing, looking at fiddler.  it keeps trying to load Getting Started page, any idea ?